# Raspberry PI ad-hoc configuration

Tags: raspberry-pi, adhoc, data-synchronization

I'm working on a project where i have two raspberry PI connected in ad-hoc mode. the project is for transmitting streaming data using UDP supported by a self developed ARQ protocol for reliable data transmission. the thing is that i want my 2 raspberry Pi to be synchronized! i tried to install the NTP server on one device and get the time on the other (as an NTP client) but when i wanted to reconnect them on ad hoc mode again, it was necessary to reboot the devices where the time was lost because the devices don't contain the hardware clock! 
is there are any idea how to synchronize the two raspberry in ad-hoc mode ?
thank you!

Comment: You could add a clock... https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/17209332-adding-a-real-time-clock-to-your-raspberry-pi

Comment: @MarkSetchell , i was thinking about this but, is there are any other way ? the idea is that i want to configure the /etc/network/interfaces on a static ad-hoc connection without rebooting the device. i've tried to use $] service network-manager restart, and other commands to restart the interface without rebooting but i didn't reach the connection !!

Comment: Do they need to be synchronised to absolute time matching the rest of the world? Or just so they both think it's the same time but that time could be different from the rest of the world? If the latter, one of them could arbitrarily say, and tell the other, that the date is midnight 2 days after the newest file it finds in `/var/log` at reboot and they could both believe that and run with it.

Comment: @Mark Setchll , the idea is to calculate the application delay for streaming data in multi-source one-destination topology. For this I need to synchronize all the node with a degree of precision to milliseconds ( or microseconds if possible) because the delay will be calculated according to the timestamp includes in the header of the packet ( the idea is simple delay = current_time - timestamp which is send_time).

Comment: So, what was the answer to my question please?

Comment: @Mark Setchell , excuses me if I didn't answer very precisely. In my case I want the end devices to run the same time (minutes, seconds, milliseconds) regardless the time in the rest of the world. Since I want to calculate the time needed to send one packet from source to destination then they must be running with same time.